# Where does americium store heat?

Tags: thermodynamics, elements

Molar heat capacity of the element americium is very close to $\frac{15}{2}R$, does that imply that each atom has 15 degrees of freedom? How does one account for them all?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that the wikipedia quoted value of 62.7 J mol$^{-1}$ K$^{-1}$ is correct. [This paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/192675681.pdf)  shows  a more reasonable value of 25 J mol$^{-1}$ K$^{-1}$ in figure 2.

Comment: Note that “62” for “26” is a common class of typographical error.

Comment: Perhaps also check the $c_p$ of nearby elements? $Pu$, $Np$ and $U$?

Comment: speaking of typos, the iron content of spinach was overstated by a factor of 10 in a nutritional handbook from the 1930's. This led to the popularity of spinach as an iron source, and Popeye The Sailor's tag-line.

Comment: Of course! That would never occur to me because that value of 62.7 is within 0.6% from $\frac{15}{2}R$ so it looked credible to me. Wikipedia has had it since 2008 and it's not allowed to be altered.